# I cannot use the result from Zxing to do my activity

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am new to Android, i want to use the data from QR code to set my textview.
and i want to test the data's result as well. 
the QR code format is just plain Text.

the problem is after I scanned my text wasn't change.

please help me check the code

```
 btnSendJob.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        //result from Zxing 
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                    // Handle successful scan

                    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultQR);
                    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textToSelectGroup);
                    text1.setText(contents.toString());

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle cancel
                    btnSendJob.setText("failed");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are getting results back in  contents and format in onActivityResult?

Comment: I don't know where i can get the result back. All I need is use the result to setText in my textview

Comment: i'm saying put  log inside onActivityResult and check result is coming back or not

Comment: Thank you for very much, but i use on a real device. and i also don't know how to test in emulator, because it doesn't have BarcodeScaner installed.

Comment: I found the solution. I have to put onActivityResult outside SetOnClickListnedr();

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this works:

```
import zxing.IntentIntegrator;


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

         IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (result != null) {
             String barcode = result.getContents();
             //yadda, yadda..
         }
}
```

Comment: thank you i found the solution. I have to put onActivityResult outside SetOnClickListnedr();